# Spring boot yml ResourceBundle file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties-file, resourcebundle

I'm using `MessageSource` of Spring to load errors messages from a `.properties` file in classpath. My properties respect a certain "template" such as `{Object}.{field}.{unrespectedConstraint}` Example :

```
userRegistrationDto.password.Size= Le mot de passe doit avoir au minimum 6 caractères.
userRegistrationDto.email.ValidEmail= Merci de saisir une addresse mail valide.
```

In case of refactoring (Changing the name of the class for example), I have to change my properties file in several places.

Is there any way to use a yaml file (messages.yml) as a ResourceBundle to obtain something like :

```
userRegistrationDto:
  password:
    Size: Le mot de passe doit avoir au minimum 6 caractères.
  email:
    ValidEmail: Merci de saisir une addresse mail valide.
```

Comment: Well, there's that (disclaimer: haven't tested it myself): https://github.com/akihyro/yaml-resource-bundle

Answer (score 11):

I think this should suffice for your requirements, if you need the MessageSource to be reloadable during VM operation, you might have to do a bit more digging.

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean(name = "testProperties")
    public Properties yamlProperties() throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean bean = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setResources(new ClassPathResource("test.yml"));
        return bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() throws IOException {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setCommonMessages(yamlProperties());
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I managed to find was found before me by @vtosh: to use [this library](https://github.com/akihyro/yaml-resource-bundle). The only problem (but still) is that it is not popular enough.

The other option could be to extend Java localization support manually extending the `ResourceBundle.Control` class (you can find an official example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html)). But I don't see much sense in it since the library @vtosh found uses this approach.

Why there is no a solution for Spring? Well, the answer you can find in [this jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14419). It is still in Open state so I don't expect to be any solution from their side at least for now.